# Array Parameterization in Module's Ports

Tags: vhdl, fpga

This question concerns the ability to define a module that can accept arrays of parametrized length.

What I currently have is:

```
use work.my_types.all;

entity Calc is
   port (clk                : in  std_logic;
         y1, y2, yc, y3, y4 : in  u8exrow;
         lap_l, lap_r       : out s9row) ;
end Calc;
```

where the types u8exrow and s9row are arrays defined in the my_types package.

I'd like the length of these arrays to vary, somehow, using generics.

This for example (besides being less nice as it doesn't use types) is not allowed:

```
entity Calc is
generic (row_end : in integer);
   port (clk                : in  std_logic;
         y1, y2, yc, y3, y4 : in  array (0 to row_end+1) of u8 ;
         lap_l, lap_r       : out array (0 to row_end) of s9) ;
 end Calc;
```

Since VHDL doesn't like arrays in its ports (for no good reason I think).

Any way of defining a module that can accept arrays of parametrized length?

Thanks!

Comment: VHDL doesn't have modules they're called design entities, comprised of an entity declaration and a matching architecture body. VHDL allows port objects of array types just fine, however you don't declare types in a port declaration's subtype indication. A type is declared separately, for a use in a port either in a package or as an interface type declaration in a generic clause (the latter not widely supported for synthesis). The type can have a deferred range provided in part by a generic constant in a port declaration's subtype indication. Your syntax isn't correct.

Comment: Do you mean the typer should be defined by: type u8row is array(integer rage <>) of u8; ?      How would the generic value define, later in the port, its length?

Answer (score 1):

VHDL doesn't have modules they're called design entities, comprised of an entity declaration (a primary unit) and a matching architecture body (a secondary unit).

VHDL allows port objects of array types just fine, however you don't declare types in a port declaration's subtype indication.

A type is declared separately, for a use in a port either in a package or as an interface type declaration in a generic clause (the latter not widely supported for synthesis, if at all).

The type can have an unconstrained range, a constraint later provided in part by a generic constant in a port declaration's subtype indication.

Your syntax isn't correct.

A package declaring array types with unconstrained ranges:

```
package my_types_deferred_ranges is
    type u8 is range 0 to 40;
    type u8row is array (natural range <>) of u8;
    type u9 is range 0 to 80;
    type u9row is array (natural range <>) of u9;
end package;
```

A Calc design entity with port declarations providing subtype indications:

```
library ieee;
use ieee.std_logic_1164.all;
use work.my_types_deferred_ranges.all;

entity Calc is
    generic (row_end : in integer);
    port (
        clk:                 in  std_logic;
        y1, y2, yc, y3, y4:  in  u8row (0 to row_end + 1);
        lap_l, lap_r:        out u9row (0 to row_end)
    );
 end entity Calc;

 architecture foo of Calc is
 begin
 end architecture;
```

When instantiated:

```
library ieee;
use ieee.std_logic_1164.all;
use work.my_types_deferred_ranges.all;

entity top is
end entity;

architecture foo of top is
    constant row_end:           natural := 25;
    signal clk:                 std_logic;
    signal y1, y2, yc, y3, y4:  u8row (0 to row_end + 1);
    signal lap_l, lap_r:        u9row (0 to row_end);
begin
INST:
    entity work.Calc  -- an enity instantiation, no component declaration
        generic map (row_end => row_end)
        port map (
            clk => clk,
            y1 => y1,
            y2 => y2,
            yc => yc,
            y3 => y3,
            y4 => y4,
            lap_l => lap_l,
            lap_r => lap_r
        );

 end architecture;
```

When these examples are analyzed in order, top may be elaborated and simulated, demonstrating the port map subtype indications are valid.

> How would the generic value define, later in the port, its length?

Analysis is the syntactical and semantic analysis of a design unit resulting in that design unit being stored in a library  akin to object files in a library archive.

Elaboration causes declarations to take effect. Think linking and loading.

Values (provided by expressions) that are unchanging after analysis are locally static. Values that are fixed at elaboration time are globally static.

Generic constants are globally static, required to be valid during elaboration. The instantiated component is elaborated with the generic value as a constraint as part of a port's subtype indication, when the port declaration's interface list is elaborated.

The subtype indication (constraints) of an object of a type can be provided by elaboration of a generic map's declarations, elaborated prior to the port map elaboration.

Comment: Nice. You could add info about package generics, such that the lengths/ranges of `u8` and `u9` are also configurable. But that might overshoot the goal.

Comment: @J.H.Bonarius - While you're at it in -2008 you can provide an subset index constraint in a subtype indication of a constrained type. Mind it may not be supported for synthesis, either. (It's that pesky [tag:fpga] tag on the question).

Comment: Thank you guys - thanks exactly what I needed!! Oh, and sorry for the "module" terms (it just makes more sense to me than entity..)

Comment: You can't effectively use the VHDL standard as a reference without embracing the language found in it.

Comment: Entity, entity, entity it is!

Answer (score 1):

In pkg:

```
type t_u8_array is array (integer range <>) of u8;
type t_s9_array is array (integer range <>) of s9;
```

Entity:

```
entity Calc is
generic (row_end : in integer);
   port (clk                : in  std_logic;
         y1, y2, yc, y3, y4 : in  t_u8_array(0 to row_end+1);
         lap_l, lap_r       : out t_s9_array(0 to row_end)
   );
 end Calc;
```

Also highly useful to be added to package (new with VHDL-2008):

```
type slv_array is array(integer range<>) of std_logic_vector;
type u_array is array(integer range<>) of unsigned;
type s_array is array(integer range<>) of signed;
```

Then using these is simply:

```
signal sMySig : slv_array(1 downto 0)(2 downto 0) := (others => (others => '0'));
```